# Get blocks between dates

Tags: blocks

I am trying to get the block between dates . for that i use web3.js . per day average block is 6172 so if i need previous day block i use below code

```
fromBlock: (await web3.eth.getBlockNumber()) - 12343, 
toBlock: (await web3.eth.getBlockNumber()) - 6172
```

then check the timestamp of the blocks in if condition .This is much time consume

is any easy way to get the blocks between dates. is any api available to get the blocks between the dates.